# What is format for coordinates of polygon in KML?

Tags: polygon, coordinates, kml, xy

I have a KML file with a polygon as shown below:

```xml
<Polygon>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
                         76.4805522843099,
                26.0253377024336 76.4805522843097,
                26.00204387482789 76.48256796531469,
                25.99713902813336 76.5136851191604,
                25.99976906336008 76.54869036032542,
                26.03246283829517 76.54426027684043,
                26.03858515622948 76.4984018904527,
                26.0253377024336 76.4805522843097,
                26.0253377024339 
            </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
    </outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
```

First coordinate that is ***76.4805522843099*** and last coordinate ***26.0253377024339***. These two coordinates are not in pair of latitude and longitude. Why is it so? Are they coordinates(latitude and longitude) of a point on the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some detail to what others have already mentioned...

A "coordinate" is a pair of numbers (aka a "tuple"): Longitude for east/west position, and Latitude for the north/south position.  In a coordinate in KML, the Lon & Lat are separated by a comma, and the coordinate pairs are separated by a space.  If you see coordinate sets in KML with three numbers, it means they include altitude (longitude,latitude,altitude).  Note that in most mapping contexts, coordinates are written with Latitude first, then Longitude, but in KML it's reversed: Longitude,Latitude

And as user30184 said, a valid polygon needs to be "closed". That means the last coordinates in the LinearRing needs to be the same as the first coordinate.  So for your example, it would need to look like the code below (I added the placemark tags to make it easy to copy/pasted in to Earth Pro).

```
<Placemark>
  <name>valid polygon example</name>

  <Polygon>
      <tessellate>1</tessellate>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
          <LinearRing>
              <coordinates>
                  76.4805522843099,26.0253377024336 
                  76.4805522843097,26.00204387482789 
                  76.48256796531469,25.99713902813336 
                  76.5136851191604,25.99976906336008 
                  76.54869036032542,26.03246283829517 
                  76.54426027684043,26.03858515622948 
                  76.4984018904527,26.0253377024336 
                  76.4805522843097,26.0253377024339 
                  76.4805522843099,26.0253377024336 
              </coordinates>
          </LinearRing>
      </outerBoundaryIs>
  </Polygon>

</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to make it a bit clearer what some of the others are saying. The problem isn't what you think where the coordinates are pairs of lat/long seperated by a space, the coords are pairs seperated by a comma, so what you have in your file is a text formatting oddity (not error). Pulling out the first three lines from the coordinates section, looks like this;

```
76.4805522843099,
26.0253377024336 76.4805522843097,
26.00204387482789 76.48256796531469,
```

The pairs are **comma-separated**, so the above becomes (when you clean up the whitespace and CR/LF issues);

```
76.4805522843099,26.0253377024336
76.4805522843097, 26.00204387482789
76.48256796531469, [parsing on the next line, etc.]
```

Next comes the problem that the first coordinate should be the same as the last, etc. as a constraint of , however you can "get around that" when parsing the file to check if they're the same, and if not add the first at the bottom of the list before you parse it further.

You haven't mentioned what systems you're using, so can't help you any further with specific behaviour of certain tools, but apart from the  constraint, there's nothing wrong with the coordinates section as such.

Hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1):

KKM files have their coordinates as longitude, latitude, i.e. first x, the y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison between longitude 76.4805522843099 and latitude 26.0253377024339 is wrong because in KML coordinates are expressed as x,y pairs or x,y,z triplets.

Thus the first coordinate is

```
76.4805522843099, 26.0253377024336
```

as the last coordinate is

```
76.4805522843097, 26.0253377024339
```

This KML geometry is still invalid because the LinearRing must be closed. From the specification  https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

```
<coordinates>...</coordinates>  <!-- lon,lat[,alt] tuples -->
```

> <coordinates>(required) Four or more tuples, each consisting of
> floating point values for longitude, latitude, and altitude. The
> altitude component is optional. Do not include spaces within a tuple.
> The last coordinate must be the same as the first coordinate.
> Coordinates are expressed in decimal degrees only.